# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'RECEPTORS.r_name' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, jdbc, playframework, sbt, multiple-tables

I am using play 2.3.8 framework to create an API and access mariaDB. When I ran the query on mariaDB console, it works OK but when I run it from play I get error that the field RECEPTORS.r_name is not available which is not true.

**My code is**

```
package models.dao

import anorm._
import models.Profile
import play.api.db.DB
import play.api.Play.current

object ProfileDAO {

def index(r_name: String): List[Profile] = {
  DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
    val results = SQL(
      """
        | SELECT `RECEPTORS.r_name`,`RECEPTORS.pdbCode`, `LIGANDS.l_id`, `LIGANDS.l_score` 
        | FROM `RECEPTORS`
        | INNER JOIN `LIGANDS`
        | WHERE `RECEPTORS.r_name`={r_name};
      """.stripMargin).on(
        "r_name" -> r_name
      ).apply()

    results.map { row =>
      Profile(row[String]("r_name"), row[String]("pdbCode"),row[String]("l_id"),row[Double]("l_score"))
    }.force.toList
  }
 }

}
```

**Query that I ran on mariaDB console is**

```
SELECT RECEPTORS.r_name, pdbCode, l_id, l_score FROM RECEPTORS INNER JOIN LIGANDS WHERE RECEPTORS.r_name="receptor";
```

**Error which running with Play 2.3.8 is as follows**

> laeeq@optiplex:~/Desktop/Backup/Project5/cpvsAPI$ sbt -jvm-debug 9999
>   run Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9999 [info] Loading
>   project definition from
>   /home/laeeq/Desktop/Backup/Project5/cpvsAPI/project [info] Set current
>   project to cpvsAPI (in build
>   file:/home/laeeq/Desktop/Backup/Project5/cpvsAPI/) [info] Updating
>   {file:/home/laeeq/Desktop/Backup/Project5/cpvsAPI/}root... [info]
>   Resolving jline#jline;2.11 ... [info] Done updating.
>
> --- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---
>
> [info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
>
> (Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
>
> SLF4J: The following set of substitute loggers may have been accessed
>   SLF4J: during the initialization phase. Logging calls during this
>   SLF4J: phase were not honored. However, subsequent logging calls to
>   these SLF4J: loggers will work as normally expected. SLF4J: See also
>   http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#substituteLogger SLF4J:
>   org.webjars.WebJarExtractor [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to
>   /home/laeeq/Desktop/Backup/Project5/cpvsAPI/target/scala-2.11/classes...
>   [info] play - database [default] connected at
>   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_profile [info] play - Application
>   started (Dev) [error] application -
>
> ! @766oc7b8l - Internal server error, for (GET) [/profiles/receptor]
>   ->
>
> play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution
>   exception[[MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column
>   'RECEPTORS.r_name' in 'field list']]  at
>   play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296)
>   ~[play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]  at
>   play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402)
>   [play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]   at
>   play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$14$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:205)
>   [play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]   at
>   play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$14$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:202)
>   [play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]   at
>   scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
>   [scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na] Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
>   column 'RECEPTORS.r_name' in 'field list'     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar:na]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote the table and column individually, so use:

```
`RECEPTORS`.`r_name`
```

otherwise MySQL  thinks you are trying to reference a column with the name `RECEPTORS.r_name` in some implicit table.

You need to do this for all your (quoted) column references. Specifically in this case, quoting seems to be unnecessary, so you could also just use `RECEPTORS.r_name` without backticks.

Comment: Thanks, it worked both ways as you suggested. Eventually I removed all back-ticks.