# Unknown column 'au_color' in 'field list'

Tags: java

I'm using windows 7, netbeans IDE 8.2, java 8 and XAMPP-workbench as DB.

My project has 2 entity classes, the session manager, and the test class. I will leave everything here below.

Any help is appreciated, and sorry for my bad English.

Superclass----------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="autos")
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
    @DiscriminatorColumn(
            name = "pe_discriminador",
            discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
    @DiscriminatorValue(value = "a1")

    public abstract class auto implements Serializable{

    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="au_marca")
    private String marca;
    @Column(name="au_modelo")
    private String modelo;

    public auto(){

    }

     public auto(String unaMarca, String unModelo)
        {
            marca = unaMarca;
            modelo = unModelo;
        }    

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getMarca() {
            return marca;
        }

        public void setMarca(String marca) {
            this.marca = marca;
        }

        public String getModelo() {
            return modelo;
        }

        public void setModelo(String modelo) {
            this.modelo = modelo;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "auto{" + "id=" + id + ", marca=" + marca + ", modelo=" + modelo + '}';
        }

    SUBCLASS ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Entity
    @Table(name="autos")
    @DiscriminatorValue("a2")
    public class auto2 extends auto{


        public auto2() {
        }


        public auto2(String color, double motor, String unaMarca, String unModelo) {
            super(unaMarca, unModelo);
            setMarca(unaMarca);
            setModelo(unModelo);
            setColor(color);
            setMotor(motor);
        }


    @Column(name="au_color")
    private String color;
    @Column(name="au_motor")
    private double motor;



        public String getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void setColor(String color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public double getMotor() {
            return motor;
        }

        public void setMotor(double motor) {
            this.motor = motor;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "auto2{"  + ", color=" + color + ", motor=" + motor + '}';
        }



    }

TESTCLASS ---------------------------------------------------------------------

      public static void main(String[] args) {

            InsertAuto2();

          }   



    public static void InsertAuto2(){
     auto2 a5 = new auto2("rojo",1.5,"name","ford");    
     Session sesion = sessionmanager.getSession();
     Transaction tx = sesion.beginTransaction();
     sesion.save(a5);
     tx.commit();
     sesion.close();
    }


SessionManager-----------------------------------------------------------------

public abstract class sessionmanager {

    private static SessionFactory factory;


  public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {

       if (factory != null) {
            return factory.openSession();
        } 
        else {

            Configuration config = new Configuration();


            registerMappers(config);


            config.setProperties(getHibernateProperties());


            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new 

    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties());
            factory = config.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());


            return factory.openSession();
        }



    }

    private static Properties getHibernateProperties() {

        Properties props = new Properties();


        props.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", 
        "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


           props.put("hibernate.connection.url", 
          "jdbc:mysql://localhost/hibernate");


        props.put("hibernate.connection.username", "root");


        props.put("hibernate.connection.password", "");


        props.put("hibernate.dialect", 
       "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");

        log4j.properties
        props.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");



        return props;

    }

    private static void registerMappers(Configuration config) throws 
    MappingException {
        config.addAnnotatedClass(entidades.auto.class);
        config.addAnnotatedClass(entidades.auto2.class);
    }
}
```

LogError------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
oct 20, 2018 5:30:19 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
oct 20, 2018 5:30:19 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
oct 20, 2018 5:30:20 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
oct 20, 2018 5:30:20 PM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
WARN: HHH000139: Illegal use of @Table in a subclass of a SINGLE_TABLE hierarchy: entidades.auto2
Hibernate: insert into autos (au_marca, au_modelo, au_color, au_motor, pe_discriminador) values (?, ?, ?, ?, 'a2')
oct 20, 2018 5:30:22 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
oct 20, 2018 5:30:22 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Unknown column 'au_color' in 'field list'
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3072)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3663)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:359)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:709)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:696)
    at testeo.TestAuto.InsertAuto2(TestAuto.java:242)
    at testeo.TestAuto.main(TestAuto.java:220)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'au_color' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3978)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3914)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2495)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1903)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2124)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2058)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5158)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2043)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Why do you have two questions open with the same title?  If they're the same question please delete one, if not, change the titles to make the differences clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well at this line:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'au_color' in 'field list'
```

i think it can't see your column and that maybe cause you didn't write your column name right or as same problem happen to someone here is the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47591698/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlsyntaxerrorexception-unknown-column-recep?rq=1)

as Mark Rotteveel answer:

> You need to quote the table and column individually

**Edit:**

okay after reading your comment and look again to your error i found this:

```
WARN: HHH000139: Illegal use of @Table in a subclass of a SINGLE_TABLE hierarchy: 
entidades.auto2
Hibernate: insert into autos (au_marca, au_modelo, au_color, au_motor, 
pe_discriminador) values (?, ?, ?, ?, 'a2')
```

and that mean you implement your statements in wrong way as in sql you insert data into your table by:

```
INSERT INTO autos ('au_marca', 'au_modelo', 'au_color', 'au_motor', 'pe_discriminador')
```

and for values you need to know what type of data your table columns use
so for Varchar values you will put your value like this "your_value"
and for boolean you will use bit only as 1 for true or 0 false
and so on.
well i hope that helped you.
also you need to tag your question as: 'java' 'Hibernate' to get more help from hibernate people.

Comment: The name of the column in the database is well written.. I'll leave an image of that underneath.

The query sql is built by hibernate, for that reason, I can not alter the structure of the query, or at least I can not think of how to do it. Do you have another suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBqU6.jpg)

This is the table that gives problems, although I think, is hibernate that causes it.